# Walmart Developer API connection

Tags: api, walmart-api

I have celigo and I am trying to connect to the Walmart API manually. The walmart API wants an epoch timestamp and an authentication key which requires me to run a jar file, and I can get those two values.

The time stamp and authentication key changes every time I run the jar file, so the connection ends up running for about 5 minutes before losing the connection. How can I make it so that it doesn't lose connection to Walmart.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using the jar to generate those two values, they will return WM_SEC.AUTH_SIGNATURE and WM_SEC.TIMESTAMP as per the documentation. These need to be generated using the jar every time you make the API call (even if you are trying to make the same API call).

It works for 5 minutes because the WM_SEC.TIMESTAMP has a validity of 5 minutes. In that case as I mentioned earlier, using the jar you will get a WM_SEC.AUTH_SIGNATURE and WM_SEC.TIMESTAMP and it will work fine for you.

Answer (score 0):

> The time stamp and authentication key changes every time I run the jar file, so the connection ends up running for about 5 minutes before losing the connection. How can I make it so that it doesn't lose connection to Walmart.

Well , timestamps and signature you generated by jar file will always change.
You said connection ends up running about 5minutes But i think its your script 
that was running for 5 min. Walmart API do not allow you to make a live connection. As soon you send request , walmart-api will respond in few seconds.

For Bulk Items Feeds upto 9.5mb(feed of 5K items) , it takes 2-3 sec maximum.

For Inventory Feeds upto 5mb (about 2K items) , it takes 2sec max.

Answer (score -1):

No, you cannot.  This is basically the entire point of the uniquely generated connection key.  It prevents connections from being left in an open state that would cause unneeded server load.

Your question doesn't identify what you are trying to accomplish, nor why you would want to maintain an open connection to Walmart.  After looking at Celigo's website, I'm still not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but based on the limited information, it appears that you are trying to do something with the Walmart API that it is not intended to do.  Connections to the Walmart API should be on a request by request basis, and do not consist of a live connection.

The Walmart API documentation indicates that you should use a uniquely generated authentication key for every request made to the API, so the fact that you are able to keep the connection alive for a full 5 minutes is even beyond what you are supposed to be doing.

What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: If you down vote, please leave a comment as to why.  The question describes wanting to do something with the Walmart API that it is not intended to do, to my knowledge.  Seeing as how I have implemented a fully featured inventory, pricing and reporting system to interface to Walmart, I believe I am pretty informed on how the connection system works.  Additionally, the question requests how to keep the connection open, without providing any detail as to what the user is trying to accomplish, which leaves me very little to work from other than, 'The Walmart API isn't designed to do that'